# Questions about the elapsed time of the time series engine in DolphinDB

Tags: time-series, streaming, dolphindb

According to [createTimeSeriesEngine](https://docs.dolphindb.cn/en/Functions/c/createTimeSeriesEngine.html?hl=createtimeseriesengine), the following aggregate operators in the time-series engine are optimized for incremental computations: corr, covar, first, last, max, med, min, percentile, quantile, std, var, sum, sum2, sum3, sum4, wavg, wsum, count, firstNot, ifirstNot, lastNot, ilastNot, imax, imin, nunique, prod, sem, mode, searchK.

Q1: Whenever a piece of data changes, incremental computation recomputes the outputs which depend on the changed inputs, and stores the intermediate results in the cache. For the aforementioned operators optimized for incremental computations, what is the parameter outputElapsedMicroseconds of the time series engine refers to?

Q2: Suppose the parameter step is set to 1, the calculation of a window is triggered every second. If a  lookup engine is serially positioned in front of the time series engine, and a row of data gets stuck in the lookup engine for 5 seconds, will the time series engine trigger calculations every second during these 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

1. step specifies the duration between windows and must be divisible by windowSize. Take the sum calculation as an example, the time series engine stores the summing results of each step in the cache. When the window moves, the engine only needs to subtract the values that are excluded from the window and add the new values that are included in the window, improving the calculation performance. The time series engine triggers the calculation of a batch of values at a time and outputs an aggregate result. Thus, the parameter outputElapsedMicroseconds determines whether to output the elapsed time from the time the calculation is triggered to the output of the result for each window.
2. If the calculation is based on the timestamps in the timeColumn, step=1 means to trigger the calculation every second, regardless of the delay in the lookup engine. However, if it is based on the system time when data is ingested into the engine, the delay of the upstream data can affect the normal output of the time series engine. To address it, you can specify the parameter fill to deal with the empty window.